# Xcode: Your session has expired. Please log in. try signing in again or contact apple developer support to resolve account access issues

Tags: xcode

I have an issue with Xcode Accounts.

I want to Sige In Xcode with my Apple ID.

But after entering, I encounter the following error:
[Your session has expired. Please log in. try signing in again or contact apple developer support to resolve account access issues]

Two Factor Authentication is one,
Phone number and email are verified,
RecoveryKey On
macOS Big Sur Version 11.0 Beta (20A5364e)
Xcode Version 11.7 (11E801a)

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to contact Apple support?

Comment: Can you log in to your developer account through a browser?

Comment: yes, I can log in with the browser.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Do you have success? I'm facing the same issue... Shame on Apple!

Comment: Same issue here as well. It is a problem related to specifically MacOS Big Sur Beta and Xcode 11. If you try with Xcode 12, it will work.

Comment: @Cleversou I reinstall macOS Catalina and install XCode 12 lead to solve my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same issue here as well. It is a problem related to specifically MacOS Big Sur Beta and Xcode 11. If you try with Xcode 12, it will work.

Comment: I reinstall macOS Catalina and install XCode 12 lead to solve my issue.

Comment: I am using Mac OS Monterey and Xcode 13.4.1. But still have the issue.

Answer (score 4):

For MacOS Monterey.

1. Open your App Store app
2. Click on Account Settings
3. then sign in with your apple ID and password

Good luck

Comment: Imagine a solution that simple

Answer (score 2):

Hello Amir and everyone else.

For me the error reason was the image bellow:

To fix, I had to:

1. Open `Xcode`
2. On Menu Bar tap `Xcode`
3. Then tap `Settings`
4. Finally tap `sign again` button as image shows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to log out of iCloud on my mac then log back in and restart to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Xcode 12 worked. But for the people that really need Xcode 11 to build their existing projects. What you can do is have both Xcode versions. I downloaded Xcode 12 and renamed my current Xcode (version 11) to Xcode-11.

And you can switch between different Xcode versions using 
`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/`

and in my use case i had to deploy to AppStoreConnect.

- I opened Xcode 12 and added account
- Went back to Xcode 11 to Archive
- Went back on Xcode 12 opened Organizer and then uploaded build to App Store Connect.

Not the cleanest but hey it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it got fixed when I tried to login to Apple support and the MacBook told me there is some error with my account login and then wanted to fix it. After I entered my password and this automatic repair process finished, also XCode login started working.